# Apache Commons EmailValidator Override isValidDomain

Tags: java, apache-commons, protected

I'm using the [Apache Commons Email validator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html)

I want to override the `isValidDomain` method, but I can't because this class has defined it with a non public constructor.

Is there anyway I can get around this besides re-writing the whole class again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method has `protected` access so you can create and use your own class extending it and override the method:

```
public class MyEmailValidator extends EmailValidator {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; // Should be Serializable 
   @Override
   protected boolean isValidDomain(String domain) {
```